# Bitbucket server REST API: Does commit API overwrite the file or will it ever have conflicts (does a merge)

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am using /rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path:.*}
to push commit to a file using Bitbucket.

I am able to do that successfully with branch, content, sourceCommitId , etc as parameters.

My question is : Do I need to worry about conflicts when using this API ? The error messages returned are about file not being present, contents not changed, etc but will there ever be a scenario where despite giving the last commit ID (in soureCommitId) , there will be conflicts ?

Does Bitbucket overwrite the file blindly ? (that would work for me)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BB will overwrite the file.

You can pass branch name instead the commit.
This will update the tip of branch.